# Add "b" prefix to python variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

Adding the prefix "b" to a string converts it to bytes:

```
b'example'
```

But I can't figure out how to do this with a variable. Assuming `string = 'example'`, none of these seem to work:

```
b(string)
b string
b'' + string
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: b converts str to bytes,not binary

Comment: whoops you're correct. Changed it.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
# only an example, you can choose a different encoding
bytes('example', encoding='utf-8')
```

In Python3:

> Bytes literals are always prefixed with 'b' or 'B'; they produce an
>   instance of the bytes type instead of the str type. They may only
>   contain ASCII characters; bytes with a numeric value of 128 or greater
>   must be expressed with escapes.

In Python2:

> A prefix of 'b' or 'B' is ignored in Python 2; it indicates that the
>   literal should become a bytes literal in Python 3.

More about bytes():

> bytes([source[, encoding[, errors]]])
>
> Return a new “bytes” object, which is an immutable sequence of
>   integers in the range 0 <= x < 256. bytes is an immutable version of
>   bytearray – it has the same non-mutating methods and the same indexing
>   and slicing behavior.
>
> Accordingly, constructor arguments are interpreted as for bytearray().
>
> Bytes objects can also be created with literals, see String and Bytes
>   literals.

Comment: so how should you do it in python 2?

Comment: If I don't know the encoding of a string, then?

Answer (score 10):

Use [`bytes()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=bytes#bytes):

```
>>> bytes("hello", encoding="ascii")
b'hello'
```

Answer (score 7):

Or use the [`bytes.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) method to convert to `string` (using a given encoding):

```py
>>> b'hello'.decode('utf-8')
'hello'
```

The opposite conversion is [`str.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) to convert a `string` to `bytes`:

```py
>>> 'hello'.encode('utf-8')
b'hello'
```

Answer (score 6):

```
string = bytes(string, encoding= 'utf-8')
```

where 'string' is your variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked for this for long time and i think the best way to convert a string into a varible is using vars()

vars()['variable name'] = value to assign

```
vars()['created_variable'] = 1
print(created_variable)
>> 1
```