# Socket programming -send in bytes

Tags: python, sockets

i saw that if i want to send in bytes something, i have to write `s.send(b'your text')`. That is good so far. But what happens if `'your text'` is stored in a variable (like `a = 'your text'`) and i want to send the variable `a` in bytes?
I assumes and tested:

```
s.send(b 'a') #does not work,it will send only 'a' as byte
s.send(b(a)) #does not work, error 'b is not defined'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add "b" prefix to python variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511440/add-b-prefix-to-python-variable)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python3, you probably want the [bytes function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytes) (which will in turn direct you to the docs of the [bytesarray function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytearray) for the detail).

You need to know the encoding of your `your text` in order to convert it to bytes. From the docs:

If [the source] is a string, you must also give the encoding (and optionally, errors) parameters; bytearray() then converts the string to bytes using str.encode().

So you will want something like `s.send(bytes(a, 'utf-8'))`.